Overlapping images in XSL-FO
We have a use case to overlap 2 images - one tiff and one jpg . We need both AFP and PDF to be generated and are using Apache FOP engine for the same.
The solution I used was to create a block container inside a table cell with absolute-position="absolute" with image as <fo:external-graphic> ,have one more block in same table cell with other image in <fo:instream-foreign-object> . This works fine when FOP creates AFP but when I try to generate PDF with same xsl, the overlapping effect does not work. I dont see image in svg. Am I missing anything ? If I cannot use same xsl template for both how do I solve this for PDF file.

Have you looked into whether FOP supports transparency in images in PDF output?

@TonyGraham Does FOP does support transparency ? I was under impression we cannot do that with FOP

It seems to me that you would see the bottom of two overlapped images only if the top image had transparent parts/background. We would have a better idea of what you mean if you added a screenshot of what works/doesn't work as well as the minimal XSL-FO to replicate it.

@TonyGraham we have to use images as it is and cannot change transparency, following is what I am trying to do and works fine when creating an AFP , only PDF is the issue, due to org policies I cannot paste snapshot or actual code, trying my best to explain you the code here

flow -> block->
table-layout="fixed"
width=100% start-indent=margin-left,right,top="0pt"
table-row height="5em" padding-right,bottom,left,top=0pt
table-cell padding-right,bottom,left,top=0pt
block-container absolute-position=absolute top=left="0"
block {First block}
external-graphic src="{images/firstPagejpgimage}" height="11in" width="8.5in"
/block
block->instream-foreign-object->svg
image height="11in" opacity="0" scaling="non-uniform" width="8.5in" xlink:href="images/firstPagelettertexttiff

the issue with above code is second image overlaps first one, the first image has pictures and second image has some text , so it should give an effect of text on a picture , hope that gives you an idea

<svg opacity="0"> should be completely transparent. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity

If you want a full-page background image, you could make one of the outer regions full size and use the image as its background-image (assuming that FOP supports that). For two images, you could use two outer regions, but you'd have to see which order FOP renders them in: with Antenna House Formatter, they are rendered in the sequence they appear in the fo:simple-page-master.
